# Ubuntu 17.04 gmd3 Boot Issues with GTX 970

Tags: boot, nvidia, gnome, 17.04, gdm

I'm making the switch from pure Debian to Ubuntu, but I'm running into issues booting into a Gnome session after install the Nvidia Graphics Drivers. 
I'm working off of a fresh install, so I'm surprised I'm running into issues.

I'm using a GTX 970 as my graphics card, and to boot into the install usb and Ubuntu I have to use `nomodeset`. This isn't an issue for me. I then installed the Nvidia drivers from the PPA. Once that's done I'm able to boot into Unity; however, I hate Unity and prefer Gnome, so I installed Gnome (more recently I just started using Ubuntu Gnome installation hoping to reduce errors somehow).

I have reinstalled the drivers and the xserver, but neither worked. The computer boots with a gray background then ends up displaying the verbose and hangs on "Removed slice User Slice of gdm." Because I can boot into Unity, I assumed this is a gdm issue. *Now, I can access a Gnome session by booting into the recovery and selecting "resume."*

The keyboard will not work when the computer is in this state (numlock won't even change). However, the gui comes up again with the spinning icon when I hit the physical button to shutdown my computer.

I have looked at other threads, but none of them have solved the problem.

Comment: Look my post bro: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062919/solved-cant-start-ubuntu-18-04-with-gtx-970-ryzen-3-2200g-gpu-has-no-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue is still unknown, but it has been fixed with the update to Ubuntu 17.10.