# Can't start Ubuntu 18.04 with GTX 970 (Ryzen 3 2200g GPU has no problem on boot)

Tags: boot, amd-graphics, pcie

I only could install Ubuntu 18.04 using the Ryzen 3 2200G GPU, because if I used the PCI-E videocard NVIDIA GTX 970, it was impossible causing the error

> kernel panic fatal exception

with all Linux distros. After installing Ubuntu 18.04, I can only access it with the Ryzen GPU because if I used GTX 970, I got only a black screen and the system gets stuck.

My PC is a dual-boot system and the GTX 970 works fine with Windows 10.

My specs are:

- Motherboard Asus A320M-K
- DDR4 2400 8GB
- SSD 120 GB Kingston (Windows 10 and boot grub)
- Seagate HDD 2TB (Linux)
- NVIDIA GTX 970
- Ryzen 3 2200G with Vega Graphics

Comment: Please do not edit your post to say "Solved" in the title, instead post what you did to solve the problem and then accept your own answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not solved. I have already been able to install correctly on Ubuntu Bionic Beaver 18.04 and Linux Mint Tara 19. The procedure was only possible this week after the appearance of the new 4.18 kernel that came with corrections for video. My procedure was with many steps but everything went well at the end:

1. I placed the HDMI cable on the integrated motherboard video (Ryzen GPU 2200G) and I usually installed Ubuntu (or Mint).
2. I updated the System and rebooted.
3. I installed the UKUU (Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility) and updated the kernel to version 4.18.
4. I turned off PC and changed the HDMI cable to the onboard GTX 960 VGA.
5. Finally worked well but some boots after got fail again.

Sorry

Btw Im using now the CentOS. It is fine and without fails (I wonder when I could try Ubuntu again...)

Comment: FYI: Ask Ubuntu is an **English-language only** website.  I have run your posts through Google Translate to get a rough approximation of what you were saying, however all answers need to continue to be in English.

Answer (score 0):

The problem returned and I had to uninstall Ubuntu. In short: I can only use linux if I use the integrated Ryzen card. I am still unable to use the GTX 970 because I can not install linux through it.